# Is there a standard session layer protocol for configuration of applications? 

Tags: c++, linux, configuration

I am in the midst of designing an application from scratch. There is one requirement that I have which I would like to fulfill using a solution which already exists.

I would like to have the transport and method for communicating configuration information to be uniform throughout the life of the application.

What does this mean? It means that using a file for configuration at load and then socket communication for later configuration is a no-go. I would like all configuration to enter the application in one way. This conduit would always be available throughout the lifetime of the application.

Futher to this, I do not want to bind myself to having to use IP. I would like to use any transport I like, including things like System V shared memory or IPC.

Is there anything out there? Do I have to create my own?

Comment: I suggest you might want to change the title as it gives the impression you might be talking about source code Configuration Management (i.e. version control)

Comment: I don't know about *standard*, but you may be looking for [GSettings](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.32/GSettings.html).

Comment: Can you tell us what application is it? And why the traditional method of reading from config file at start and further changes via signal isn't desired in your scenario? BTW, shared mem seems good alternative as it is async.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the following will provide exactly the functionality you are looking for, but it might provide some room for thought...

Let's assume your application is called `myApp`, and the `-cfg <...>` command-line option is used to specify the source of its configuration. You could allow the following options...

`myApp -cfg /path/to/configuration/file.cfg`

The above is obvious: read configuration from the specified file.

`myApp -cfg "exec#curl -sS http://configWebServer/path/to/file.cfg"`

The `exec#` prefix specifies that the specified command should be executed. It is expected that the command will write to standard output. That standard output is then parsed as a configuration file.

By the way, `curl` stands for [*cat URL*](http://curl.haxx.se/). It is is an open-source utility that can retrieve files using a variety of protocols, including HTTP(S), FTP(S), LDAP and so on. The `-sS` command-line options to `curl` tell it to not print diagnostics except for error messages, which is probably what you want.

The `"exec#..."` format paves the way to retrieve configuration information using other means. For example, from a script that queries a database, from a Subversion repository, or whatever you want.

You might want to also support the following variation:

`myApp -cfg "shared_lib=foo#..."`

That will load a shared library called `foo`, and call an entry-point function in it, passing `"...`" as a parameter. It will be up to the shared library function to decide how to act upon the parameter. One implementation of the shared library might retrieve configuration information from shared memory; another implementation might retrieve it via a remote procedure call or a socket connection; and so on.

All the different retrieval mechanisms have *only* the responsibility retrieving the configuration data as a (potentially large) string. For example, the `-cfg /path/to/file.cfg` mechanism reads the entire contents of the file and returns it as a string (or perhaps as a `std::istream`). That (potentially large) string is then passed to the "real" configuration parser (a parser for XML/ini/properties file or whatever).

I believe that the above proposal provides a solution for half of your question. In particular, it provides a plug-in architecture to retrieve configuration data from arbitrary sources, where the plug-in can be written as a shell command or a shared library.

The other half of your question is basically: "How can the application dynamically retrieve updated configuration data during its lifetime?" I haven't addressed that requirement. Partially because I don't have an elegant solution to offer. And partially because you have not indicated what might trigger the re-reading of configuration data.

By the way, I am the maintainer of a C++/Java configuration parser library called [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/). That library provides an implementation of the `"exec#..."` functionality. I mention that in case you want to examine the source code to see how such functionality can be implemented. I suspect the code required to support `"shared_lib=foo#..."` could be easily modelled on the existing code for supporting `"exec#..."`. The "Config4* Getting Started Guide" (available from the website in PDF and HTML formats) provides a good discussion of the `-cfg "exec#..."` functionality, including a security mechanism to prevent people from trying to execute malicious commands.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers my question at all - and I wonder if your main point was a plug for your parser library ;). I specifically would like **all** configuration to enter the application via one conduit. The files you allude to above are static - if the method was to "tail" them and watch them grow, pull in more configuration, that might be a solution.

Comment: Your question appears to have two requirements: (1) to *not* hardcode the technology used to access config data; and (2) to have a trigger for re-accessing config data when it has changed. My proposed solution to (1) is that you use a plug-in architecture, and I suggested two approaches for implementing that. I don't have a solution for (2), and, in my opinion, you haven't provided a clear description of your requirement for (2). Since my proposed solution to (1) does not meet your requirements, perhaps you could edit your question to restate your requirements more clearly.

Comment: As you suggest, tailing a file (or periodically polling a socket connection) to see if there is new configuration data is one way to get updates. However, it ties up a thread in your application. If your application is single-threaded, then that might not be acceptable. The suggestion from tuxuday to re-read a (presumably updated) config file whenever a signal is received seems good. Can you explain why his proposal does not meet your requirements?